# Выражение "зарубежные страны"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему выражение "зарубежные страны" является приемлемым? В случае произнесения такой фразы, подразумевается, что существует обратная — "внутрирубежные" страны, что выглядит весьма странно. Если использовать единственное число в последней — выходит также нелогично, ведь можно вполне употребить одно слово вместо двух. Прошу объяснить логику или происхождение данного выражения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика данной фразы:
Зарубежные страны - находятся за рубежом страны рассказчика. То есть в понятие "**страны**" входит сама **страна рассказчика** (наша страна) и **остальные страны** (зарубежные = внешние), которые находятся за её рубежом. В данном смысле "зарубежные" означает "другие". Антонимом к этой фразе будет **страна рассказчика**, которая находится **внутри** своих границ.

Выражение не идеально, но употребляется по той причине, что особо и нет вариантов, которые означают то же самое и хорошо звучат. Можно разве что заменить на "другие страны".

Answer (score 1):

Не подразумевается. Не у всех слов есть антонимы или "обратные" фразы, как вы их назвали (пример - "подзаборный").

Логика очень простая. Есть граница - рубеж. Страны по ту сторону рубежа находятся за рубежом - зарубежные.

Comment: В таком случае это тем более нелогично. Человеку заведомо известно о фразе то, что она подразумевает "рубеж". Я в своей логике не отталкиваюсь от "обратных" фраз, это было в качестве примера. Всё, что находится за рубежом, это уже не внутренняя, так сказать, территория. Фраза используется в контексте _подчёркивания_ различия между территориями. То есть, **все** другие страны уже находятся за рубежом. Следовательно, по-моему, словосочетание не несёт дополнительного смысла и является лишней в речи. Могу быть не прав, поправьте, если так.

Comment: Хорошо, а как сказать это без использования слова "зарубежные"? Другие страны? Прочие страны? В любом случае требуется какое-то прилагательное, и "зарубежные" здесь не хуже других. И даже лучше

Comment: Сойдусь во мнении. Звучит, может, и не так логично, если разбирать, но иные синонимы в настоящем языке не очень прижились.

Answer (score 1):

Да нормальная там логика. Есть твоя страна, и есть другие страны, которые за рубежом. Может и есть какие-то корявости, но их давно узаконили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта книга в СССР года до 65-го была по сути единственным справочным пособием обо всех странах мира.